# jquery, flexslider - controlNav: "thumbnails", hangs the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

controlNav: "thumbnails", hangs the browser

I am using the below code to show flex slide show the code is taken from demo/index.html

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    //controlNav: "thumbnails",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
  $slider = $(".flexslider").data('flexslider');

  $slider.addSlide('<li><img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" /></li>', 1)

});
```

when the code (controlNav: "thumbnails",) is uncommented my browser gets hanged and the page become unresponsive, i need to kill the page forcefully

i am using chrome Version 31.0.1650.48

i have also created issue on github https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/917